# Inner-Join MS Access to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, inner-join

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Connect(strVar As String)
Dim strEmps As String, strPath As String
strEmps = "SELECT fldStudentNo, fldFirstName,fldLastName,fldTelephone, fldDepartmentName, fldClassDate, fldClassName"
strEmps = strEmps & "FROM [tblDepartments] INNER JOIN tblStudents ON "
strEmps = strEmps & "[tblDepartments].fldDepartmentNo = tblStudents.fldDeptNo "
strEmps = strEmps & "WHERE fldDepartmentName = '" & strVar & "' ORDER BY fldLastName"
strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & cstrPath
Set connEmp = New ADODB.Connection
Set rstEmps = New ADODB.Recordset
connEmp.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & strPath & "'"
rstEmps.Open strEmps, connEmp, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Call DisplayData
End Sub
```

I need to write the Access inner join (below) into the above code in Excel. I dont understand how to do multiple inner joins. Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
SELECT tblStudents.fldStudentNo, tblStudents.fldFirstName, tblStudents.fldLastName, tblStudents.fldTelephone, tblDepartments.fldDepartmentName, tblClasses.fldClassDate, tblClasses.fldClassName
FROM (tblDepartments INNER JOIN tblStudents ON tblDepartments.[fldDepartmentNo] = tblStudents.[fldDeptNo]) INNER JOIN (tblClasses INNER JOIN tblStudentsAndClasses ON tblClasses.[fldClassNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldClassNo]) ON tblStudents.[fldStudentNo] = tblStudentsAndClasses.[fldStudentNo];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use short table aliases you can get away from long table names repeated over and over. That should help to reduce the confusion.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Connect(strVar As String)
    Dim strEmps As String, strPath As String
    dim connEmp as New ADODB.Connection
    dim rstEmps as New ADODB.Recordset
    strEmps = "SELECT s.fldStudentNo, s.fldFirstName, s.fldLastName, s.fldTelephone, d.fldDepartmentName, c.fldClassDate, c.fldClassName"
    strEmps = strEmps & " FROM tblDepartments d"
    strEmps = strEmps & " INNER JOIN tblStudents s ON s.[fldDeptNo] = d.[fldDepartmentNo]"
    strEmps = strEmps & " INNER JOIN tblStudentsAndClasses sc ON sc.[fldStudentNo] = s.[fldStudentNo]"
    strEmps = strEmps & " INNER JOIN tblClasses c  ON c.[fldClassNo] = sc.[fldClassNo]"
    strEmps = strEmps & " WHERE d.fldDepartmentName = '×××' ORDER BY s.fldLastName;"
    strEmps = replace(strEmps, "×××", strVar)
    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & chr(92) & cstrPath  '.Path doesn't usually end in a backslash
    debug.print strPath
    connEmp.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & strPath & "';"
    set rstEmps = connEmp.Execute(strEmps)
    Call DisplayData
    rstEmps.close: set rstEmps = nothing
    connEmp.close: set connEmp = nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Without setting up a full test environment, this is probably closer to what you are looking for. As you haven't disclosed the value of `cstrPath`, I added a backslash to `thisworkbook.path`. Also note that I've prefaced the concatenated strings with spaces so the lines didn't run into each other.